# How to use rTorrent's schedule property

Tags: bittorrent, rtorrent

I've seen rtorrent.rc files with a schedule property as follows:

```
schedule = watch_directory,5,5,load_start=~/torrent/torrent/*.torrent
```

What do the arguments mean? What is `watch_directory`? Why are two 5 ints being passed in? What does `load_start` mean?

I havent been able to find answers anywhere on the web. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

schedule = [ user defined name of event] [seconds to apply command after start program] [seconds before applying command again] [command]

In this case load_start is a command that takes a list of files and loads/starts them in rtorrent (assuming the files are all torrents).

The name of the event is not relevant I believe, perhaps only when throwing errors.

Comment: Can you link me to whatever docs you learned this from? Thank you